# Fixing error in a pine script Stock Screener

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert above script in a pine screener in this way and , I would search only best BUY conditions so I need to verify in screener the condition longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1 and shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1.
I have this

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Screener)", overlay=false)

// Stocks
s1 = input('NSE:JSWSTEEL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s2 = input('NSE:TATASTEEL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s3 = input('NSE:DIVISLAB', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s4 = input('NSE:HDFCBANK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s5 = input('NSE:GRASIM',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s6 = input('NSE:ULTRACEMCO',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s7 = input('NSE:KOTAKBANK',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s8 = input('NSE:INFY',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s9 = input('NSE:AXISBANK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s10 = input('NSE:CIPLA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s11 = input('NSE:INDUSINDBK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s12 = input('NSE:SBIN',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s13 = input('NSE:TECHM',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s14 = input('NSE:HEROMOTOCO',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s15 = input('NSE:ICICIBANK',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s16 = input('NSE:BAJAJFINSV',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s17 = input('NSE:EICHERMOT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s18 = input('NSE:DRREDDY',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s19 = input('NSE:HDFCLIFE',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s20 = input('NSE:TITAN',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s21 = input('NSE:BHARTIARTL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s22 = input('NSE:TATAMOTORS',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s23 = input('NSE:LT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s24 = input('NSE:TCS',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s25 = input('NSE:HDFC', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s26 = input('NSE:BRITANNIA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s27 = input('NSE:ITC', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s28 = input('NSE:NTPC',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s29 = input('NSE:BAJFINANCE', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s30 = input('NSE:MARUTI',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s31 = input('NSE:HINDUNILVR',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s32 = input('NSE:WIPRO',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s33 = input('NSE:SUNPHARMA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s34 = input('NSE:NESTLEIND',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s35 = input('NSE:ASIANPAINT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s36 = input('NSE:RELIANCE', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s37 = input('NSE:M_M',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s38 = input('NSE:HCLTECH',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s39 = input('NSE:UPL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s40 = input('NSE:SBILIFE',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")




///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(close, 100, 3.0)
rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(close, smrng)
upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])
hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng
filtcolor = upward > 0 ? color.lime : downward > 0 ? color.red : color.orange
barcolor = close > filt and close > close[1] and upward > 0 ? color.lime : 
   close > filt and close < close[1] and upward > 0 ? color.green : 
   close < filt and close < close[1] and downward > 0 ? color.red : 
   close < filt and close > close[1] and downward > 0 ? color.maroon : color.orange


longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := close > filt and close > close[1] and upward > 0 or 
   close > filt and close < close[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := close < filt and close < close[1] and downward > 0 or 
   close < filt and close > close[1] and downward > 0
CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]


// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 



    longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
    shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1
   

// Rounding Function
roundn(x, n) => 
    mult_local = 1 
    if n != 0
        for i = 1 to abs(n)
            mult_local := mult_local * 10
    
    n >= 0 ? round(x * mult_local) / mult_local : round(x / mult_local) * mult_local 

///////////////////////////////////////
// Running Functions for all sybmols //

[v1, c1] = security(s1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v2, c2] = security(s2, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v3, c3] = security(s3, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v4, c4] = security(s4, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v5, c5] = security(s5, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v6, c6] = security(s6, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v7, c7] = security(s7, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v8, c8] = security(s8, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v9, c9] = security(s9, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v10, c10] = security(s10, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v11, c11] = security(s11, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v12, c12] = security(s12, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v13, c13] = security(s13, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v14, c14] = security(s14, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v15, c15] = security(s15, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v16, c16] = security(s16, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v17, c17] = security(s17, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v18, c18] = security(s18, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v19, c19] = security(s19, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v20, c20] = security(s20, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v21, c21] = security(s21, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v22, c22] = security(s22, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v23, c23] = security(s23, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v24, c24] = security(s24, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v25, c25] = security(s25, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v26, c26] = security(s26, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v27, c27] = security(s27, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v28, c28] = security(s28, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v29, c29] = security(s29, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v30, c30] = security(s30, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v31, c31] = security(s31, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v32, c32] = security(s32, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v33, c33] = security(s33, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v34, c34] = security(s34, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v35, c35] = security(s35, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v36, c36] = security(s36, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v37, c37] = security(s37, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v38, c38] = security(s38, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v39, c39] = security(s39, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v40, c40] = security(s40, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

////////////////////
// Screener label //

f_buildLabel(_c, _s, _v) =>
    _c ? _s + ' ' + tostring(roundn(_v, 3)) + ' :: ' : ''
    
if barstate.islast
    scr_label = ''
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c1, s1, v1)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c2, s2, v2)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c3, s3, v3)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c4, s4, v4)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c5, s5, v5)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c6, s6, v6)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c7, s7, v7)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c8, s8, v8)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c9, s9, v9)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c10, s10, v10)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c11, s11, v11)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c12, s12, v12)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c13, s13, v13)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c14, s14, v14)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c15, s15, v15)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c16, s16, v16)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c17, s17, v17)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c18, s18, v18)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c19, s19, v19)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c20, s20, v20)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c21, s21, v21)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c22, s22, v22)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c23, s23, v23)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c24, s24, v24)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c25, s25, v25)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c26, s26, v26)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c27, s27, v27)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c28, s28, v28)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c29, s29, v29)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c30, s30, v30)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c31, s31, v31)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c32, s32, v32)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c33, s33, v33)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c34, s34, v34)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c35, s35, v35)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c36, s36, v36)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c37, s37, v37)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c38, s38, v38)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c39, s39, v39)
    scr_label := scr_label + f_buildLabel(c40, s40, v40)

    
    
    scr_label := scr_label + ""
    
    // Plot Label
    lab_l = label.new(
              bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
              color=color.green, 
              textcolor=color.white, 
              style =  label.style_labeldown,
              yloc = yloc.price)
```

but there is something wrong since I receive errors.

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 107: Cannot destructure
> expression of type 'series[bool]'. Tuple expected.

**How to fix it ?**

Answer (score 0):

The code had a few issues:

`security()` cannot return "bool" values, so they must be converted to int/float, which is done with:

```
    longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1 ? 1 : 0
    shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1 ? 1 : 0
```

The code is designed to expect a `screenerFunc()` to return a tuple, which is done with:

```
    [longCondition, shortCondition]
```

Your calculations used mutable variables (variables whose values are reassigned with the `:=` operator), which cannot be handled with `security()` unless the variables are used inside a function. The relevant code was thus included in the `screenerFunc()` function.

Also, the `f_buildLabel(_c, _s, _v)` function wasn't building useful information for display.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (Screener)", overlay=false)

// Stocks
s1 = input('NSE:JSWSTEEL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s2 = input('NSE:TATASTEEL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s3 = input('NSE:DIVISLAB', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s4 = input('NSE:HDFCBANK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s5 = input('NSE:GRASIM',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s6 = input('NSE:ULTRACEMCO',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s7 = input('NSE:KOTAKBANK',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s8 = input('NSE:INFY',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s9 = input('NSE:AXISBANK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s10 = input('NSE:CIPLA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s11 = input('NSE:INDUSINDBK',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s12 = input('NSE:SBIN',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s13 = input('NSE:TECHM',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s14 = input('NSE:HEROMOTOCO',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s15 = input('NSE:ICICIBANK',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s16 = input('NSE:BAJAJFINSV',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s17 = input('NSE:EICHERMOT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s18 = input('NSE:DRREDDY',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s19 = input('NSE:HDFCLIFE',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s20 = input('NSE:TITAN',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s21 = input('NSE:BHARTIARTL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s22 = input('NSE:TATAMOTORS',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s23 = input('NSE:LT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s24 = input('NSE:TCS',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s25 = input('NSE:HDFC', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s26 = input('NSE:BRITANNIA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s27 = input('NSE:ITC', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s28 = input('NSE:NTPC',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s29 = input('NSE:BAJFINANCE', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s30 = input('NSE:MARUTI',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s31 = input('NSE:HINDUNILVR',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s32 = input('NSE:WIPRO',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s33 = input('NSE:SUNPHARMA',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s34 = input('NSE:NESTLEIND',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s35 = input('NSE:ASIANPAINT',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s36 = input('NSE:RELIANCE', type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s37 = input('NSE:M_M',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s38 = input('NSE:HCLTECH',   type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s39 = input('NSE:UPL',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")
s40 = input('NSE:SBILIFE',  type=input.symbol, group = "Symbols")




///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m
    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(close, 100, 3.0)
rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r : 
       x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt

// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 
    filt = rngfilt(close, smrng)
    upward = 0.0
    upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
    downward = 0.0
    downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])
    hband = filt + smrng
    lband = filt - smrng
    filtcolor = upward > 0 ? color.lime : downward > 0 ? color.red : color.orange
    barcolor = close > filt and close > close[1] and upward > 0 ? color.lime : 
       close > filt and close < close[1] and upward > 0 ? color.green : 
       close < filt and close < close[1] and downward > 0 ? color.red : 
       close < filt and close > close[1] and downward > 0 ? color.maroon : color.orange
    
    
    longCond = bool(na)
    shortCond = bool(na)
    longCond := close > filt and close > close[1] and upward > 0 or 
       close > filt and close < close[1] and upward > 0
    shortCond := close < filt and close < close[1] and downward > 0 or 
       close < filt and close > close[1] and downward > 0
    CondIni = 0
    CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]

    longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1 ? 1 : 0
    shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1 ? 1 : 0
    [longCondition, shortCondition]

// Rounding Function
roundn(x, n) => 
    mult_local = 1 
    if n != 0
        for i = 1 to abs(n)
            mult_local := mult_local * 10
    
    n >= 0 ? round(x * mult_local) / mult_local : round(x / mult_local) * mult_local 

///////////////////////////////////////
// Running Functions for all sybmols //

[v1, c1] = security(s1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v2, c2] = security(s2, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v3, c3] = security(s3, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v4, c4] = security(s4, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v5, c5] = security(s5, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v6, c6] = security(s6, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v7, c7] = security(s7, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v8, c8] = security(s8, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v9, c9] = security(s9, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v10, c10] = security(s10, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v11, c11] = security(s11, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v12, c12] = security(s12, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v13, c13] = security(s13, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v14, c14] = security(s14, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v15, c15] = security(s15, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v16, c16] = security(s16, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v17, c17] = security(s17, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v18, c18] = security(s18, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v19, c19] = security(s19, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v20, c20] = security(s20, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v21, c21] = security(s21, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v22, c22] = security(s22, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v23, c23] = security(s23, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v24, c24] = security(s24, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v25, c25] = security(s25, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v26, c26] = security(s26, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v27, c27] = security(s27, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v28, c28] = security(s28, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v29, c29] = security(s29, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v30, c30] = security(s30, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v31, c31] = security(s31, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v32, c32] = security(s32, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v33, c33] = security(s33, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v34, c34] = security(s34, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v35, c35] = security(s35, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v36, c36] = security(s36, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v37, c37] = security(s37, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v38, c38] = security(s38, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v39, c39] = security(s39, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
[v40, c40] = security(s40, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())

////////////////////
// Screener label //

f_buildLabel(_c, _s, _v) =>
    string _return = ""
    _return += _c or _v ? _s + ': ' : ''
    _return += _c ? '▲' : ''
    _return += _v ? '▼' : ''
    _return += _return == '' ? '' : ' :: '
    
if barstate.islast
    scr_label = ''
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c1, s1, v1)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c2, s2, v2)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c3, s3, v3)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c4, s4, v4)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c5, s5, v5)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c6, s6, v6)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c7, s7, v7)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c8, s8, v8)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c9, s9, v9)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c10, s10, v10)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c11, s11, v11)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c12, s12, v12)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c13, s13, v13)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c14, s14, v14)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c15, s15, v15)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c16, s16, v16)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c17, s17, v17)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c18, s18, v18)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c19, s19, v19)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c20, s20, v20)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c21, s21, v21)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c22, s22, v22)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c23, s23, v23)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c24, s24, v24)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c25, s25, v25)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c26, s26, v26)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c27, s27, v27)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c28, s28, v28)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c29, s29, v29)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c30, s30, v30)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c31, s31, v31)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c32, s32, v32)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c33, s33, v33)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c34, s34, v34)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c35, s35, v35)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c36, s36, v36)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c37, s37, v37)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c38, s38, v38)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c39, s39, v39)
    scr_label += f_buildLabel(c40, s40, v40)
    
    // Plot Label
    label.new(
              bar_index, 0, scr_label, 
              color=color.green, 
              textcolor=color.white, 
              style =  label.style_labeldown,
              yloc = yloc.price)
```

[image]